# button_to block in presenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, presenter

I'm using `button_to` inside the presenter. This works fine. However if I create a block I receive the error

```
undefined method `stringify_keys'
```

I'm wondering if it's even possible to use a `button_to` block outside of a view file.

```
# Inside my presenter class

# The line below causes the error
button_to 'Big Button', '/', {} do
  link_to('Home', '/', { })
end.html_safe
```

How can I fix this? Am I missing something rather obvious?

Comment: Why you actually want to show a link into a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to show a link inside of a button, but, you can try this:

```
button_to '/', { ... } do
  'Big Button'
  link_to('Home', '/', { ... })
end.html_safe
```

You don't need to include a label as a first argument to your `button_to` block.

Comment: Thanks. What if I have options that I want to pass to the `button_to` method? I guess I pass them inside the elements in the block?

Comment: Can you tell me your intention functionality-wise? In `button_to` as well as `link_to` you are redirecting user to '/'. Why this nesting?

Comment: Forget why I have a `link_to` inside a `button_to`. `link_to` could be a `content_tag`. This was a simplified example.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it will help you.